# How to add custom link in title when post photo from Facebook iOS SDK

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk

I try to add a custom link in the title when user post photo from a iOS app.

like this:[pic](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vfm93jr5gm344x1/Screen%20Shot%202013-05-11%20at%2010.10.33%20PM.png)

My code is:

```
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    @" - Via www.google.com", @"message",
                                    aUIImage, @"picture",
                                    nil];


    FBRequestConnection *newPhotoConnection = [[FBRequestConnection alloc] init];

    FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestWithGraphPath:@"me/photos" parameters:params HTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    [newPhotoConnection addRequest:request completionHandler:nil];
    [newPhotoConnection start];
```

And I get:[pic](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zhe4ynn0bjm4ypr/Screen%20Shot%202013-05-11%20at%2010.31.02%20PM.png)

So how to add custom link in the title? Do I need to add any setting in facebook app setting? Thanks!!

Comment: I'm pretty sure the Piictu app uses Open Graph instead of just normal photo uploads: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

Comment: Yea, thanks a lot. By the way I have another question, how to add custom link in the title when posting photo from iphone? (like when you comment at facebook website, you type "@" then you can tag your friend and fan pages). So in this way I can add a custom link that is linked to my fan page. Thanks~